# Adding Two Different Activities in A Single Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I just wanted to create a view in Android which is like this:

http://anish-panthi.net.np/design/Design.jpg

Comment: I was not allowed to post jpg file in here so different link was created. I'm trying ur suggestion. Thankyou for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create two FrameLayout inside main activity.
2. create two separate fragments (first/second) and add those to the Framelayout using FragmentManager.

Answer (score 0):

There could be only one Activity on the screen. But `Activties` could have many `Fragments` inside, please read: [fragments google](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: I've gone through this, but my requirement is different. So in confused how to start and from where to start.

Comment: @AnishPanthi: "but my requirement is different" -- please edit your question to explain, **completely and precisely**, what this "requirement" is.

Comment: The requirement is: First Activity is fragment in which i have to select 2 fields from spinner and based on that spinner the result will be displayed in 2nd fragment which is Second Activity in above figure.